# A native exception has occurred in

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, native-code

I am using [a code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcpe/archive/2006/03/03/542941.aspx) to capture image from mobile device, unfortunately it shows the following error msg:

A native exception has occurred in TimedCamera.exe.

when I clicked on details, it shows the following:

> ExceptionCode: 0xc0000005
>   ExceptionAddress: 0x78b21be0
>   Reading: 0x00000020
>   Faulting module: cameracapturedll.dll
>   offset: 0x00001be0

I would really appreciate if anyone could suggest me possible ways to solve that problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's an access violation from a read operation.

The address of the read (`0x20`) is likely due to reading a field from a structure when the pointer is null. This could be due to a bug in the dll, or due to your code passing a null pointer into the dll.